# Setting default font size in TinyMCE is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and I want to set the default font-size to 12.

Here, I assigned a variable to the active TinyMCE editor, but it's not working...

**HTML content:**

```
<textarea id="text_message"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#text_message").tinymce({        
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url: '/static/app/a/scripts/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
});

var fontSize = 12;
tinyMCE.activeEditor.formatter.apply('fontSize', 
{
    value: fontSize
});
```

Comment: Which kind of backend do you use?

Comment: I hope this help http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css

Comment: but if you want to use formatter you should register one,and only after thet you will be able to apply For more details take a look here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.Formatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different event stages you should wait for:

1. The page is ready in some state. (`tinyMCE.init()` can also be used, depending on the situation.)
2. The editor has been initialized and is ready for you to being working on it.

The first can be accomplished using either:

```
$(document).ready()
```

Or:

```
$(window).load()
```

Both handle events related to the readiness of the page. `$.ready()` triggers when the DOM is available, `$.load()` in the case of `window` triggers when the page content has been loaded (such as inline `img`, `script`, and `link` sources). `.ready()` fires slightly before the other, but in many cases either will work.

<sup>Note, below I've got `jQuery(function($){...});` which is a shortcut to `$(document).ready();` and helps manage conflicts with other frameworks that use `$` globally.</sup>

At the second stage you need to add an [initialization event handler](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainit_instance_callback) to your editor creation request, such as:

```
$.tinymce({ init_instance_callback: function(){ ... } });
```

In full:

```
$tiny.tinymce({
    // ... other stuff here, comma-delineated
    init_instance_callback: function(){
        ac = tinyMCE.activeEditor;

        ac.dom.setStyle(ac.getBody(), 'fontSize', fontSize);
    }
    // ... other stuff here, comma-delineated
});
```

Here is where you can set the *display* value for `font-size` (using the Javascript property of `fontSize`, since Javascript doesn't allow `-` in labels such as `font-size`). This waits for the editor you're adding to initialize and say "Hey, I'm here now". Once you get that notification of the vent firing, you can set the editor `body` (what `ac.getBody()` returns) to be `font-size: 18px`.

What this means is that the `font-size` will not be returned once you choose the save the editor content; it's above it in in the editor "body" (literally, the `iframe`'s `body` element), in most cases (unless you choose the [`plugins : "fullpage"` initialization option](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full_page.php)). So it's a "default", but does not get set explicitly within the content itself.

If you have Chrome or Firefox with Firebug add-on installed, watch the `console` on this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/9PuUx/1/

Here is the working code demo and link to a fiddle demo (I use `18px` to easily see the change):

```
jQuery(function a($){
    var $tiny = $("#text_message"),
        fontSize = '18px',
        ac;

    $tiny.tinymce({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fontsizeselect,bold,underline,italic",
        init_instance_callback: function(){
            ac = tinyMCE.activeEditor;

            ac.dom.setStyle(ac.getBody(), 'fontSize', fontSize);
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/9PuUx/

The tinyMCE documentation and API can be a bit confusing and lacking, and I'm not an expert in using it either, so I know there's perhaps four or five other ways to interpret what's going on and how to do this. Your mileage may vary. If you have an issue with the way I did this or it does not seem to do what you want or expect, just leave a comment and let me know.