# Accessing the wysihtml5 editor object to use it inside "events"?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I found this in the [documentation of bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5):

```
The underlying wysihtml5 object
You can access the wysihtml5 editor object like this:

var wysihtml5Editor = $('#some-textarea').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor;
wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("bold");
```

So I tried this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var myCustomTemplates = {
    link : function(locale) {
      return "<li>" +
        "<div class='bootstrap-wysihtml5-insert-link-modal modal hide fade'>" +
          "<div class='modal-header'>" +
            "<a class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</a>" +
            "<h3>" + locale.link.insert + "</h3>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='modal-body'>" +
            "<input value='http://' class='bootstrap-wysihtml5-insert-link-url input-xlarge'>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='modal-footer'>" +
            "<a href='#' class='btn' data-dismiss='modal'>" + locale.link.cancel + "</a>" +
            "<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary' data-dismiss='modal'>" + locale.link.insert + "</a>" +
          "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<a class='btn' data-wysihtml5-command='createLink' title='" + locale.link.insert + "'><i class='icon-link'></i></a>" +
      "</li>";
    },
    "font-styles": function(locale, options) {
      return "<li>" +
        "<a class='logo'>Logo</a>" +
      "</li>" +
      "<li>" +
        "<a class='btn btn-paragraph' data-wysihtml5-command='formatBlock' data-wysihtml5-command-value='p'>" + locale.font_styles.p + "</a>" +
      "</li>" +
      "<li>" +
        "<a class='btn btn-paragraph' data-wysihtml5-command='formatBlock' data-wysihtml5-command-value='p'>" + locale.font_styles.p + "</a>" +
      "</li>";
    }
  }


  $('#wysihtml5-textarea').wysihtml5('deepExtend', {
    "font-styles": true, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
    "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
    "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
    "html": true, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
    "image": false, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
    "link": false,
    "format-code": false, // enable syntax highlighting
    customTemplates: myCustomTemplates,
    "events": {
      "focus": function() { 
        //var wysihtml5Editor = $('#wysihtml5-textarea').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor;
        //wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML", "<a href=...>");
      }
    },
    parserRules: {
      tags: {
        p: {}
      }
    },
    "stylesheets": ["<%= root_url %>wysiwyg-color.css", "<%= root_url %>github.css"], // CSS stylesheets to load
  });
 </script>
```

But it seems like it is breaking the code:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/posts/lib/css/wysiwyg-color.css 404 (Not Found)
```

And `wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec` is not working either.

(The file loads just fine if I don't include the content inside `"focus": function() {`)

What the right way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried binding the `focus` function to the `wysihtml5Editor` variable, and using it as this inside the event handler?

Comment: @helly0d Sorry I'm not very good at JavaScript, could you give me an example?

Comment: You're showing us a a constructor call and then point to an error associated with a file `404` error on a CSS file? I'm confused. Is the file available at that path? Can you copy/paste it into your browser and view the file?

Comment: if you could post more of your code maybe we could pinpoint you in the right direction.

Comment: @Jared Farrish The file loads fine if I don't include the code inside `"focus": function() { ` I was just showing that the code breaks.

Comment: @helly0d OK, I posted the whole thing.

Comment: Ahh, you didn't mention or describe the issue *within* the question text; I missed it, obviously, in the question title. I see what you're saying. Can you http://jsfiddle.net a demo for us to look at? I suspect it's that you're not waiting for the page to be ready before initializing the editor call.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Ha, I'm not sure how to jsfiddle it, it is a Ruby on Rails plugin.

Comment: @JaredFarrish this is the live demo: http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542646/setting-default-font-size-in-tinymce-is-failing/12556006#12556006) and see if that helps (it covers TinyMCE, but they're perhaps not that different in this situation). This was a similar situation.

Comment: @Jared Farrish OK, thanks. (Sorry, its not a Rails plugin. I will try to jsfiddle it).

Comment: Here's a fiddle demo of what's on that page you linked: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nWebx/

Comment: @Jared Farrish Thanks I will check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here's a minimally working code, to use as a starting point:

```
// I use this to keep this code out of the global scope. 
// This takes this form: (function($){...})(jQuery);
// and allows me to use $ without worry about it interfering
// with other libraries and frameworks that share it's use.
(function priv($) {
    // This is another scope thing; I can set the reference
    // later on, but it will be in the parent scope, so I
    // can cache these and then access them from within a
    // window.onload handler, for instance, that I create 
    // further down.
    var $editor,
        opts;

    // A more elegant, clean way of doing what was in the docs.
    opts = {
        // Note, it's not necessary to use quotes on labels in
        // object notation, UNLESS there's something not allowed.
        // This and format-code have comments ONLY because they
        // have that infernal dash in there. No others in this 
        // list do, however.
        'font-styles': false,
        'format-code': false,
        emphasis: true,
        lists: true,
        html: false,
        image: false,
        link: false,
        events: { 
            // Passing a reference to a function I've declared
            // later. I could not have this before the actual
            // functions, though, if I use var onload = function...
            // since "hoisting" does not occur. So, be careful
            // emulating this too liberally if you don't under
            // why it works.
            load: onload,
            focus: onfocus,
            blur: onblur
        }
    };

    // I'm using the `window.onload` method to setup my editor
    // AFTER the page has loaded and the DOM is ready. 
    $(window).on('load', function load() {
        // See, I set this up here, and can access it in the
        // onload, onfocus, and onblur handlers without 
        // requerying. It's called caching a reference.
        $editor = $('#wysihtml5-textarea');

        $editor.wysihtml5(opts);
    });

    function onload() {
        console.log('load');
    }

    function onfocus() {
        console.log('focus');
    }

    function onblur() {
        console.log('blur');
    }

})(jQuery);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nWebx/5/

---

I put the [wysihtml5 editor demo](http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) in a [properly running fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nWebx/) and then modified it to run your referenced code:

```
$(window).on('load', function load(){
    /*$('.textarea').wysihtml5();
    $(prettyPrint);*/

    $('#wysihtml5-textarea').wysihtml5('deepExtend', {
        "font-styles": true, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
        "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
        "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
        "html": true, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
        "image": false, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
        "link": false,
        "format-code": false, // enable syntax highlighting
        customTemplates: myCustomTemplates,
        "events": {
            "focus": function() { 
                var wysihtml5Editor = $('#wysihtml5-textarea').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor;
                wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML", "<a href=...>");
            }
        },
        parserRules: {
            tags: {
                p: {}
            }
        },
        "stylesheets": ["<%= root_url %>wysiwyg-color.css", "<%= root_url %>github.css"], // CSS stylesheets to load
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nWebx/2/

With this as-is, I receive this error in Chrome Console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myCustomTemplates is not defined

So I comment that line out, and it runs. Try it:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nWebx/1/

Now, I am running the editor code within a `window.onload` event using jQuery's `$.on()` event handler method:

```
$(window).on('load', function load(){
    $('#wysihtml5-textarea').wysihtml5('deepExtend', {
        ...
    });
}) // <<< I'd try to always using `;` at the end of statements.
```

And I also get no errors with the `focus` handler, although I need to check that it's event running to beginning with. So, what is in `myCustomTemplates`?

Comment: Thanks for the help (I will check your code). Please see my edit, I posted the whole thing.

Comment: I tried the last demo. So the event is not inserting anything?

Comment: No, the event isn't running, at least in my fiddle. Your error suggests it is being seen (which references the css file).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. So you are having the same problem that I am having or another one? (the stylesheet part can be removed, its not really necessary).

Comment: When you have issues like this, you need to stop and start stripping out stuff you don't need to make the script work. So I'm pulling things out (cutting) one at a time and rerunning to see what happens. Then I'll build it back up from scratch, one line or statement at a time, until I find the problem. Here's where I'm at right now: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nWebx/3/ Everything works, so now I'll start to re-add stuff, first trying to get the event option to work (by itself). It's time consuming, but also time-proven.

Comment: I think I'm not used to jsfiddle.net I forked your fiddle, and added  the events, but I'm getting a bunch of errors in the console: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nWebx/3/ EDIT: Oh, never mind I think I have to add them in the left panel.

Comment: I've got the fiddle working in a basic way: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nWebx/5/ Note, I've made several choices and changes, so it looks different. But take a look at it with a console window open, click in and out, and you should see it log `load`, `focus`, and `blur`. So I've met my first objective: Get the code minimally working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (I've learned some stuff today). I will play with it on my localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var wysihtml5Editor = $('#some-textarea').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor;
wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("bold"); 
var focusHanlder = function(){
     console.log(wysihtml5Editor);
     wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML", "<a href=...>");
}

var secondFocusHandler = function(){
    console.log(this);
    this.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML", "<a href=...>");
}.bind(wysihtml5Editor);
```

where `focusHandler` uses the exterior variable `wysihtml5Editor` and `secondFocusHanlder` uses that variable as `this` inside the call. Now pass one of those variable to the `focus` event.

Here is a little example of using the events on wysihtml5Editor: https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Events

Comment: @hello0d strange, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined`

Comment: On which one? Bind or non bind?

Comment: that means only one of the following: Either you are not waiting for `DOMload` to be completed or you haven't actually initialized the `wysihtml5Editor` properly.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a link ( i think you've been there, if not than take a look );

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that with https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5 you define events inside  `"events": {` So I'm getting confused there. The documentation just says what I posted up in the question (not sure if I did it right though).